# unsubscribe does not exist on type Observable<>?

Tags: angular

I am trying to unsubscribe from an observable in ngOnDestroy, but it is telling me it does not exist on type Observable.

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public caseData;

  constructor(private _caseService: CaseService,
              private _title: Title,
              private _metaService: Meta) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._caseService.GetCaseData('en', 'English');
    this._caseService.caseData$.subscribe(res => { this.caseData = res },
      (error) => { console.log(error) });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._caseService.caseData$.unsubscribe(); //says it does not exist
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The subscription itself is returned.

```
  subscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this._caseService.GetCaseData('en', 'English');

    this.subscription = this._caseService.caseData$.subscribe(res => { this.caseData = res },
      (error) => { console.log(error) });

  }
  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.subscription.unsubscribe(); 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks.  This worked.  If I am using async in other components, I don't need to unsubscribe, correct?

Comment: In general it's better practice to unsubscribe to avoid memory leakage, but that's true for async pipe, it takes care of it for you

Answer (score 2):

`unsubscribe()` is a method of a `Subscription`, not an `Observable`.

Answer (score 0):

That should work:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public caseData;
  subscription: any;

  constructor(private _caseService: CaseService, private _title: Title, private _metaService: Meta) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._caseService.GetCaseData('en', 'English');
    this.subscription = this._caseService.caseData$.subscribe(res => { this.caseData = res },
      (error) => { console.log(error) });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For better way to handle subscription I recommend checking these two links:

https://medium.com/thecodecampus-knowledge/the-easiest-way-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-in-angular-5abde80a5ae3

and

[Angular/RxJs When should I unsubscribe from `Subscription`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription)